Integrating C++ Classes into CLR Project for Windows Forms Application: Parser Error Issue
I have created a CLR empty project (.NET Framework) in Visual Studio, as I've learned that this is the preferred method to utilize C++ with an effective GUI. Within this project, I have a form named MyForm, with its associated file MyForm.h containing all the code.
I've placed some C++ classes in a file named MyClass.h, along with their implementations in a separate C++ file. Now, I wish to utilize one of these classes within my form. Initially, I included MyClass.h at the beginning of MyForm.h, and proceeded to create an object of that class. While it works for the most part – the form successfully updates its text using a function from the class – I now encounter an issue.
Attempting to open MyForm.h[designer] prompts the following error message:

C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 222, Column: 12 --- Unknown type
'MyClass'. Please ensure that the assembly containing this type is
referenced. If this type is part of your development project, ensure
that the project has been successfully built.

I've struggled to find helpful resources online regarding the correct usage of a C++ class within a form file. As a student proficient in C++, I lack expertise in integrating it with other components. Additionally, within MyClass.h, I'm solely utilizing the std namespace. Could this potentially lead to namespace conflicts, or perhaps I need to reference my class or wrap it in a specific manner?"
I've attempted various troubleshooting steps, including cleaning and rebuilding the solutions, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution

The problem is that the WinForms designer is .NET based, and doesn't cope well with C++ native classes.
In these kind of applications I suggest splitting the code into 3 parts, each in a separate VS project:

GUI application. Can be written in C# which is more convenient IMHO, but if you prefer C++/CLI it can also work. This should be a bormal WinForms application project.

A C++/CLI wrapper around the native C++ logic. This should be a .NET DLL, with a thin layer that converts the native C++ classes into .NET ones. The GUI application will have a reference to this project and consume it. In order to create it in VS you can start with a C++ DLL project, and in the project settings add Common Language Runtime Support (/clr).

The native C++ classes. This can be either a native DLL or a static library. The .NET wrapper above should link with it.


Among other advatages this architecture will solve the problem you have with the GUI designer.

It seems I made a bit of a rookie mistake. I had inadvertently placed the instantiation of the myClass object and its function in the 'properties' section of the MyForm.h code. i think that section is typically reserved for declaring properties like those of text boxes, not for executing code. By relocating these lines to the MyForm_Load function, which triggers when the form loads, I managed to resolve the issue with the designer.
Thanks for your assistance! If any further hiccups arise, I'll keep this approach in mind.

Moved the object instantiation and the call of its function to the myForm_Load function which has seemed to fix the issue
